# Is there a way to disable auto save in Mineraft PE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

In Minecraft PE, I was building something with friends, and someone else joined and started blowing up everything. This is extremely annoying. How do I disable autosave in Mincecraft PE?

(I am running ios 8.1.1 and MCPE 0.10.4)

Comment: Which OS are you using, Android, iOS, or others?

Comment: Hmm... For Androids, it's possible to find the game files and do a back up, but for iOS, I'll leave that to others who know the answer.

Comment: Ahh. Try this thread but the files recommended may not be safe. Use at own risk. http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-discussion/1964663-is-it-possible-to-backup-share-a-world

Answer (score 1):

No there isn't sorry. I've want to go back as well before and looked online and didn't find anything.

Comment: Well isn't that just one unconstructive answer. (@EnoughGinger50, some things are not as simple as a [Google Search](https://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=disable%20autosave%20minecraft%20pocket%20edition).) | And of course, everyone knows it's not a feature... *Yet*.

Comment: @aytimothy In a game like Minecraft where "no take-backs" is a deliberate part of the design, figuring out how to go back to an old save is called "save scumming." Save scumming is never a future feature of these games, on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You can use pocketmine to host a dedicated server. In pocketmine, you can use save-off command. Or you can just install a password or non grief plugin.

Currently pocketmine server isn't supported for ios. (For misunderstandings: You can join and play but you can't host.) If one of your friends have android, you can use that to host.

Btw. You can use your iphone but it needs to be jailbroken.